# Text wrapping on tables in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, table, formatting

I currently have a table (not a text box) that I'd like to have overlaid on the map in layout view of ArcMap 10.3. It, unfortunately, has a long title in the column. So, when I go to put the table on the map, it looks very elongated and generally not great. Is there a way that I can text-wrap the titles, and potentially also center-justify the data within the table? Neither the Options menu under Customize nor the Properties menu appear to have any helpful fixes.

I guess if there really isn't any other option, I could just make a text box and then align everything by hand, but obviously this isn't preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a table to the layout basically just captures a screenshot of however it looks in the attribute table view.

In the table options menu for your attribute table click on **Appearance**...

Change the Cell Height value to something larger. For font size 10, 200% should work for titles with 2 lines, or 300% for 3 lines, etc.

Then simply re-size the field to give you the desired effect and add it to your layout.

[image]